# Error loading wikidata on local blazegraph

Tags: jetty, wikidata, blazegraph

I have installed locally wikidata and blazegraph following the instruction here : https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

The .munge get me 424 files as "wikidump-000000001.ttl.gz" in data/split

When I try to load one file on blazegraph I get an error :

> ERROR:
>   uri=[file:/mnt/d/thomas/wikidata/dist/target/service-0.2.1/data/split/wikidump-000000001.ttl.gz],
>   context-uri=[] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: Expected an RDF value here, found
>   '' [line 1]

Comment: Are you loading files using `loadRestAPI.sh`?

Comment: I load it with ./loadRestAPI.sh -n wdq -d pwd/data/split/wikidump-000000001.ttl.gz (from the link above) or from the blazgraph server localhost:9999/bigdata/#update with the path

Comment: So I understand that the loading doesn't work even in Blazegraph workbench? Looks like something is not right with that .ttl.gz file, could it be posted somewhere?

Comment: here you are, thanks for your time : https://drive.google.com/a/recital.ai/file/d/1X9xxXi4WVJYVMMTQlo64EyoTN3MEaKdL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wikidata on local Blazegraph : Expected an RDF value here, found '' \[line 1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020506/wikidata-on-local-blazegraph-expected-an-rdf-value-here-found-line-1)